# How to select row value with loc/iloc without getting the index and column name as well?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe and I'm trying to get the cell value with .loc:

```
dataframe.loc[[index_value], [column_name]]
```

The problem is the result includes the index number on the left and column name on top, but I only want the value. How do I isolate it?

Here is the actual code + result:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Use `df.at` and drop the square brackets around the row and column index:

```py
df.at[random.randrange(len(jeopardy)), "question"]
```